# Plot within a plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to create a smaller plot within a plot in MATLAB, for example like the image of [this MATLAB File Exchange Upload](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35245-matlab-plot-gallery-plot-in-plot/content/html/Plot_in_Plot.html).
There, two figures are created and then both of them are plotted in one figure.

My problem however is that I already have two MATLAB figures from earlier simulations and I need to embed one figure into the other one, i.e., one would be small and the other plot would be big but in the same graph. Could someone suggest an easy way to do this?

Comment: How do you have the existing MATLAB figures? As `*.fig` files?

Comment: Yes, both of them are `*.fig ` files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using the [`copyobj`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyobj.html) function. You'll need to copy the Axes object from one figure to the other:

```
f(1) = openfig('fig1.fig');
f(2) = openfig('fig2.fig');

ax(1) = get(f(1),'CurrentAxes');                % Save first axes handle
ax(2) = copyobj(get(f(2),'CurrentAxes'),f(1));  % Copy axes and save handle
```

Then you can move and resize both axes as you like, e.g.

```
set(ax(2),'Position', [0.6, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2]);
```